# jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user

Tags: java, sql, connection

I keep getting the error:

> "jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user"

in my Java program using IntelliJ.

This is part of my code:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=CityJailOriginal;user=student;password=test";
try 
{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
}
```

SQL server is configured, according to the research I have done, correctly. I have created the user student and is related to a login devClass that contains password test. I have tried placing devClass instead of test in the password area, but I keep getting the same error. I have tried what has been suggested in other posts, but it is not working for me.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!! =)

Comment: I could be wrong since I am not awfully experienced with jdbc but I believe you are missing a semicolon in your connection string. try `String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=CityJailOriginal;user=student;password=test";`

Comment: See also: https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-url-format.  You can pass the username and password as parameters in the `getConnection` call.

Comment: Sorry! the missing semicolon was a copy-paste error. The code does have the semi colon. Still getting the same error.